# where django create InMemoryUploadedFile object of uploaded file?

Tags: django, file-upload, django-uploads

when a HTTP Post request came with a file , django will create a InMemoryUploadedFile instance for each uploaded file.
I'd like to extend InMemoryUploadedFile and add a few field and finally customize the upload file behavior of django.
I took a look on django.middlewares but I didn't fined any middleware related to this behavior.
how django does this ?
how can I customize this behavior ?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question.
there is a setting in django for this purpose called [FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#file-upload-handlers)
the only thing we need to do is creating a new File Handler class which can be an extended version of either MemoryFileUploadHandler or TemporaryFileUploadHandler .
after creating this new class we should add our class name to the FIRST item in the tuple for FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS.
for more documentation please take a look at [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/files/uploads/)